# Regex to grab number in line

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping

I have an html file that I am reading the below line from. I would like to grab only the number that appears after the ':' and before the ',' using REGEX... THANKS IN ADVANCE

```
"totalPages":15,"bloodhoundHtml"
```

Comment: Does it have to be a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"totalPages":([0-9]*),
```

You can see the Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/kD9kR9/3)

Then the python code is

```
import re

p = re.compile('"totalPages":([0-9]*),')
print p.findall('"totalPages":15,"bloodhoundHtml"')
```

Comment: this is good but what if the number 15 is not always going to be 15?

Comment: but arent we searching for a line specific to 15 in the findall?

Comment: No the regex is defined in the line above. In findall we define the text we want to analyze.

Comment: I suggest you to read the official python doc about how to use regex https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try `:\d+,` to get the ':15,'
then you can trim first':' and trim end ',' to get the pure numbers,
I don't know if python can use variable in the regex, I'm a c# programe, in c#, I can use `:(?<id>\d+),` to match this string, and get the number directly by `result.group["id"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
:\d{1,},
```

Also works for parsing the line you gave. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1) post, you might run into some trouble parsing the HTML

Comment: so would it be something like re.compile('"totalPages":\d{1,},"bloodhoundHtml"'